# How to check if key with specific value exists in JSON object?

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON object like this:

```
{
    people: [
        {
            id: "id1",
            name: "name1",
            description: "Desc"
        },
        {
            id: "id2",
            name: "name2",
            description: "Desc2"
        },
        {
            id: "id3",
            name: "name3",
            description: "Desc3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to check if an id with value of "id2" exists, is there any utils in java that allow me to do this without iterating through all objects and comparing String with target?

P.S. I don't want to know if 'id' field exists using JSONObject.has(key), this is not what I'm asking.

Comment: Use a JSON parser, traverse the JSON object graph and find what you are looking for.

Comment: There's no way to search a collection without traversing it.

Comment: Google Java json parsers. Any one of those.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the net.sf.json library. With that library the [JSONObject](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html) has a method contains(String key) which returns a Boolean based on if the key exists or not. If you are looking to search like this a lot I would suggest looking into that library or Google's gson library to make it easier on you.